# Equivalence between ellipse definitions

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

In a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvdRnEYiQD4) by MathyJaphy, the creator uses a geometric\kinematic way to describe the focus and directrix definition of the ellipse (or, equivalently, the slice-of-a-cone definition). He even created [a desmos file](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fuzoeddcma) if anyone wants to play with it a bit.

When the moving line goes faster than the expanding circle, it draws an ellipse. I understand why it's equivalent to the conic section definition of the ellipse (or the focus and directrix one), but I can't see in a straightforward way why it's gives the same result as the two foci definition, or the squashed circle one (or for that matter - why the resulting shape is symmetric).

Does anyone have a simple explanation why they're all the same?
Ideally, it would be with as little algebra as possible, and without using [Dandelin spheres](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pQa_tWZmlGs) (at least, without introducing a third space dimension). Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: FYI: A site search for ["ellipse equivalent definition"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=ellipse+equivalent+definition) yields $50+$ results, at least some of which may be relevant. Can you say something about why the answers to these questions may be unsatisfactory, so that people don't spend time and effort duplicating responses you won't like?

Comment: I've looked through them, and all of them either uses an excessive amount of algebra, assume a second focus, or uses Dandelin spheres

Comment: My answer doesn't use algebra, proves the existence of a second focus and doesn't need Dandelin spheres. Is it fine for you, or not?

Comment: It is helpful and interesting, but it's not exactly what I've looked for - it doesn't use the "kinematic" construction that I've mentioned, and what ultimately triggered my curiosity

Comment: It's a different kinematic construction, clearly exhibiting that symmetry you want to understand.

Answer (score 1):

We need first of all a nice lemma:

> In a right triangle $ABC$, let $E$ be a point on hypotenuse $AB$ and
> $D$ a point on the extension of $BA$ after $A$ (see figure).  Then
> $\angle DCA=\angle ACE$ if and only if $DA:EA=DB:EB$.

Proof. If $\angle DCA=\angle ACE$ then by the angle bisector theorem (in triangle $DCE$) we have
$$DA:AE=DC:CE.$$
On the other hand, $BC$ turns out to be the bisector of exterior angle $\angle ECF$ (because $\angle ECB=\angle BCF=90°-\angle ACE$) and by the exterior angle bisector theorem we get
$$BD:BE=DC:CE.$$
Comparing the above results we thus find:
$$DA:EA=DB:EB,$$
as it was to be proved. The converse is obvious by the unicity of the construction and can be easily proved by RAA. $\square$

[image]

Let's see now how one can construct points on an ellipse, given a focus $S$, its directrix $XM$ (with $SX\perp XM$, see figure below) and its eccentricity $e<1$.
We first construct the major axis $AA'$ of the ellipse, and then pairs of points, symmetric about the perpendicular bisector of $AA'$.

On segment $SX$ we can in fact construct a point $A$, such that $SA:AX=e$. And on the extension of $XS$ we can construct another point $A'$, such that $SA':A'X=e$. Points $A$ and $A'$ belong then to the ellipse and are by definition the endpoints of its major axis.

> Take now any point $M$ on the directrix. Through $M$ and $S$ draw line
> $MYSY'$, meeting lines $AY$ and $A'Y'$, drawn at right angles to $AA'$, at
> points $Y$ and $Y'$. On $YY'$ as diameter describe a circle and draw
> line $MPP'$ parallel to $AA'$, intersecting the circle at points $P$
> and $P'$. Then $P$ and $P'$ lie on the ellipse.

Proof. We have $SY : YM = SA : AX$
and $SY': Y'M = SA' : A'X$, whence:
$$SY : YM = SY': Y'M.$$
But $YPY'$ is a right triangle and we can apply the lemma proved above, obtaining that $PY$ is the bisector of $\angle MPS$. From the angle bisector theorem we then have:
$$
PS:PM=SY:YM=SA:AX=e,
$$
hence $P$ lies on the ellipse. We can repeat the same reasoning for right triangle $YP'Y'$, to prove that $P'$ is also on the ellipse. $\square$

By construction, $P$ and $P'$ are symmetric about the perpendicular bisector $OC$ of $AA'$ (the projection of the midpoint $O$ of $YY'$ on line $AA'$ is in fact the midpoint $C$ of $AA'$).

> It follows that we could consider another focus $S'$ and another
> directrix $X'M'$, reflections of $S$ and $XM$ about $OC$, and we would
> get the same ellipse.

[image]

Finally, let's prove that $SP+S'P=AA'$ for any point $P$ of the ellipse.
From
$$SA':A'X=SA:AX$$
we get
$$SA':SA=A'X:AX 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
(SA'+SA):SA=(A'X+AX):AX,$$
that is:
$$AA':SA=XX':AX, 
\quad\text{or}\quad 
AA':XX'=SA:AX.$$
From that and $SP:PM=SA:AX$ one then gets
$$SP:PM=AA':XX'.$$
In the same way one obtains
$$S'P:PM'=AA':XX'$$
and combining the last two equalities we find
$$(SP+S'P):(PM+PM')=AA':XX'.$$
But $PM+PM'=MM'=XX'$, hence:
$$SP+S'P=AA'.$$

Here's an animation made with GeoGebra, showing how points $P$ and $P'$ trace out the ellipse.

[image]